# Fail of query when use subquery

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, subquery

I have a problem with PostgreSQL 9.5 when I select columns and I use json_build_object, I have an error with GROUP BY clause.

I have three tables:

```
Table contact

  Colonne  |           Type           
-----------+--------------------------
 id        | integer                  
 lastname  | character varying(255)   
 firstname | character varying(255)
```

This table is a table of contacts

```
Table companie

  Colonne  |           Type           
-----------+--------------------------
 id        | integer                  
 name      | character varying(255)
```

This table is a table of companies

```
Table companie_contact

  Colonne  |           Type           
-----------+--------------------------
 id        | integer                  
 id_c      | integer                  
 id_cm     | integer
```

This table is a many-to-many relation to link contacts with companies and vice versa.

When I execute this query all works

```
SELECT co.id,
json_build_object(
  'lastname', co.lastname,
  'firstname', co.firstname) AS contact,
array_agg(c.name) AS companies
FROM companie AS c
INNER JOIN companie_contact AS vs
ON c.id = vs.id_cm
INNER JOIN contact AS co
ON co.id = vs.id_c
GROUP BY co.id;
```

I get

```
 id |                    contact                   |  companies
----+----------------------------------------------+-------------
  1 | {"lastname" : "some", "firstname" : "one"}   | {A,B,D,E,F}
  4 | {"lastname" : "some", "firstname" : "two"}   | {A}
  2 | {"lastname" : "some", "firstname" : "three"} | {B}
```

But when I replace contact and companie by View or by a subquery
Like below

```
-- Imagine that the views are more complex than that
CREATE VIEW view_contact AS SELECT * FROM contact

CREATE VIEW view_companie AS SELECT * FROM companie

SELECT co.id,
json_build_object(
  'lastname', co.lastname,
  'firstname', co.firstname) AS contact,
array_agg(c.name) AS companies
FROM view_companie AS c
INNER JOIN companie_contact AS vs
ON c.id = vs.id_cm
INNER JOIN view_contact AS co
ON co.id = vs.id_c
GROUP BY co.id;
```

I got this error

```
ERROR:  column "co.lastname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function 
LINE 1: SELECT co.id,json_build_object('lastname', co.lastname, 'fi...
```

I don't know why I have this error, I didn't find solution to my specific problem on web

Thanks you for your help

PS: Sorry for my english I'm french

Comment: Do you have the not working query at hand? That would be helpful in combination with the error but others may be able to answer already based on the facts given ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT co.id,
json_build_object(
  'lastname', co.lastname,
  'firstname', co.firstname) AS contact,
array_agg(c.name) AS companies
FROM companie AS c
INNER JOIN companie_contact AS vs
ON c.id = vs.id_cm
INNER JOIN contact AS co
ON co.id = vs.id_c
GROUP BY co.id, co.firstname, co.lastname,c.name ;
```

Comment: It works but that will become really dirty if I have more fields

Comment: Aggregate functions often need an added GROUP BY statement.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: If you want to pass more field to aggregate functions then you must add them to group by clause.

Comment: In this case, why when I use tables in FROM and JOIN clauses, it works, I don't need to add more GROUP BY statements, but when I use subqueries or views in FROM and JOIN clauses, I need to add more GROUP BY statements ?